# String replace using replace first method

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I was trying to use the string replace with another, it doesn't happen.

```
String requestURI = "/webapps-ab/public/Test.jsp"
String contextName = "webapps-ab";
String newRequestURI = requestURI.replaceFirst(contextName,"webapps");
```

I am expecting `newRequestURI` to be `"/webapps/public/Test.jsp"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `replace` call should be:

```
String newRequestURI = requestURI.replaceFirst(contextName, "webapps");
```

Using:

```
String requestURI = "/webapps-ab/public/Test.jsp";
String contextName = "webapps-ab";
String newRequestURI = requestURI.replaceFirst(contextName, "webapps");
System.out.println("newRequestURI: " + newRequestURI);
```

The output will be what you're expecting:

```
newRequestURI: /webapps/public/Test.jsp
```

[ideone example](http://ideone.com/hKz09).

Comment: I tried the same piece of code but still see the old request URI. Does '/' make any difference.

Comment: @1078081 you must have typos remaining. See the link to the ideone version producing the expected output

Comment: I am running the code exactly as pb2q has posted it and am seeing the correct output. Could you please post what the exact code is you're running?

Comment: It it working now. In my real code, I didn't notice that there are some upper case letters. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When referencing a variable, do not surround it in quotes, as that converts it into a literal String object.

```
String newRequestURI = requestURI.replaceFirst(contextName, "webapps");
```